# How to form SoapClient method parameters for XML attributes?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to integrate a SOAP service into our app. For the `UpdateCart` method, their documentation states that it requires four properties. However, in their WSDL, which can be found here https://mews.mouser.com/cartservice.asmx?WSDL, it shows that it only requires a single property. Normally I would call the method via a SoapClient like so:

```
$soapClient->UpdateCart(array('xmlCartMessage' => $value));
```

Following their documentation, I should call it like so:

```
$soapClient->UpdateCart(array(
    'CartGUID' => $value1,
    'Requestor' => $value2,
    'MouserPartNumber' => $value3,
    'Quantity' => $value4
));
```

However, it doesn't work. It gives me the following error:

```
"faultstring":"Server was unable to process request. ---> String reference not set to an instance of a String.\nParameter name: s","faultcode":"soap:Server","detail":""
```

Their documentation states that the request for `UpdateCart` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CartMessage CartGUID="" Requestor=“ADI” xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <CartItem MouserPartNumber="595-430F157IPM" Quantity="37" TransactionID="1" CountryCode=""/>
</CartMessage>
```

I noticed that the parameters are encoded as attributes rather than tags with values. How am I supposed to do it using `SoapClient`?

Comment: give me your wsdl file url

Comment: @NathanSrivi: Is this what you're asking: https://mews.mouser.com/cartservice.asmx?WSDL ? I included it above, FYI. Thanks!

Comment: ok wait i will check it and update you

Comment: can you give your documentation url

Comment: @NathanSrivi: Give me a sec.

Comment: @NathanSrivi: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_hNukFoLpVBbnFYQ2VOSExFd0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok wait for some seconds

Comment: give me the string value <xmlCartMessage>string</xmlCartMessage>

Comment: i am checking update cart

Comment: @NathanSrivi: That's actually the problem I'm facing. I don't know how to put a value for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $soapClient->__doRequest() to submit the request. For example, assuming $soapClient is initialised and that their example request is valid, try something like:

```
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CartMessage CartGUID="" Requestor=“ADI” xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CartItem MouserPartNumber="595-430F157IPM" Quantity="37" TransactionID="1" CountryCode=""/>
</CartMessage>
';

$location = "https://mews.mouser.com/cartservice.asmx?WSDL";
$action = "http://tempuri.org/UpdateCart";
$result = $soapClient->__doRequest($request, $location, $action, 1);
```

$location and $action will need to be set based on the their WSDL.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to create a SOAP call like:

```
<Element Name="John" Group="USER">DATA</Attribute>
```

You should try something like this:

```
array('Element ' => array('_' => 'DATA', 'Name'=>'John', 'Group'=>'USER'));
```

So in Your case I assume it should be:

```
$CartItem = array('CartItem' => array('_' => '', 'CartGUID'=>$value1, 'Requestor'=>$value2));
$CartMessage = array('CartItem' => array('_' => $CartItem, 'MouserPartNumber'=>$value3, 'Quantity'=>$value4));

$soapClient->UpdateCart($CartMessage);
```